# How to make upper shadow for button in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-cardview, shadow

[image: Button with dropshadow(black) and upper shadow(white)]

I want to make a button like this. I used cardview to give the radius and drop shadow effect. But only dropshadow does not gives an edgy style like in the image above.
Here is my code for creating this type of button:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/tuna2"
            app:strokeColor="@color/gun_powder"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            app:contentPadding="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView28"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/transfer"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/dm_sans"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView23"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView28"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView28"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView28"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

This code creates a button like in the image below:
[image: Button with no upper white shadow]

How can I make the button look like the sun is hitting from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

drawable/custom_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#41445F"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="40dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#303348"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="40dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and set background in `ConstraintLayout` layout like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_bg">
```

output like this

[image]